# WriteConcern detected an error cased by assertion in btree.cpp:390

Tags: mongodb

When I am saving documents in monogdb, getting the following error:

```
WriteConcern detected an error 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 
0 assertion src\mongo\db\structure\btree\btree.cpp:390'. 

(Response was { 
    "ok" : 1, "code" : 8, "err" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 0 
    assertion src\\mongo\\db\\structure\\btree\\btree.cpp:390", "n" : NumberLong(0) 
})
```

Any help please?

Comment: Related [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/GLg82RmRURU).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the code is failing during [`verify()` assertion call](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6.3/src/mongo/db/structure/btree/btree.cpp#L390) while adding a key into a bucket. This error should come with extra details in the log file such as:

> btree bucket corrupt? consider reindexing or running validate command klast: X  key: Y

which suggets that your btree bucket could be corrupted.

So consider repairing your database by:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```

then reindex if necessary.

Also make sure you've enough free space on your device and got the right read and write permissions. If this happens often, either it's a bug or fault of your storage device.